# Conditional expectation on independent copy

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let $X \overset{D}{=} X_{1}$ be an independent copy of a continuous random variable $X$, where $X$ is on probability space $(\Omega, F, \mathrm{P})$. Let $A$ be another random variable, where $E (A\mid X)$ is known. Further, $X$ and $X_{1}$ depend on $A$. I am trying to show that
\begin{equation}
E (A\mid X) = E (A\mid X_{1}).
\end{equation}
If counterexamples exist, please state them.

Consider $G_1 \subseteq G_2 \subseteq F$,
where $G_1= [\emptyset, \Omega]$ is the trivial sigma-algebra and $G_2=\sigma(X)$.

My attempt is the use the law of iterated expectation
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{E}\left[\mathrm{E}\left[X \mid G_2\right] \mid G_1\right]=\mathrm{E}\left[X \mid G_1\right],
\end{equation}
precisely
\begin{equation}
E (A\mid X_{1}) = E(E(A\mid X)\mid X_{1}). 
\end{equation}
to show the statement of interest. I believe that $G_2=\sigma(X_{1})$, but I am not sure, as I struggle with the measure theoretical understanding of what an independent copy actually is.

Comment: The claim isn't true

Comment: @Andrew okay, please point to a counterexample.

Comment: Take $X_1$ independent of $A$, and $X$ not independent of $A$

Comment: Okay, to be more precise. Let $X_{1}$ and $X$ depend on $A$. I will change it above.

Comment: It can't be in general since $E(A \mid X)$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable, whereas $E(A \mid X_1)$ is $\sigma(X_1)$-measurable. Equality (a.s.) will happen if and only if $E(A \mid X) = E(A \mid X_1) = E(A).$

Comment: Okay, thank you @WilliamM.